# Multiple Timer Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have a page where I want show multiple countdowns. I made a javascript code that makes the countdown and it works on all divs that i specify, but this goes in real time only on the last div. Can someone help me? I posted the page below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Timer(){
this.countdown=function(fineanno, finemese, finegiorno, fineore, fineminuti, finesecondi, nomediv)
{
var_div=nomediv;
var_anno=fineanno;
var_mese=finemese;
var_giorno=finegiorno;
var_ore=fineore;
var_minuti=fineminuti;
var_secondi=finesecondi;
data_scandeza= new Date(var_anno,var_mese-1,var_giorno,var_ore,var_minuti,var_secondi);
data_oggi= new Date();
differenza=(data_scandeza-data_oggi);
giorni=parseInt(differenza/86400000);
differenza=differenza-(giorni*86400000);
ore=parseInt(differenza/3600000);
differenza=differenza-(ore*3600000);
minuti=parseInt(differenza/60000);
differenza=differenza-(minuti*60000);
secondi=parseInt(differenza/1000);
differenza=differenza-(secondi*1000);
if (giorni <= "0" && ore <= "0" && minuti <= "0" && secondi <= "0")
{
document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML="Tempo scaduto";
}
else
{
document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML=giorni +' giorni '+ore+' ore '+minuti+' min '+secondi+' sec';
setTimeout("t"+var_div+".countdown(var_anno, var_mese, var_giorno, var_ore, var_minuti, var_secondi, var_div)",1000);
}
}
}
</script>






</head>
<body>

<div id="div2"></div>
<script>
var tdiv2 = new Timer();
tdiv2.countdown("2013","04","26", "23","00","00","div2");

</script>

<div id="div3"></div>
<script>
var tdiv3 = new Timer();
tdiv3.countdown("2013","04","26", "23","00","00","div3");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you prefix your variables with `var_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_div`, `var_anno`, `var_mese`, `var_giorno`, `var_ore`, `var_minuti` and `var_secondi` are global variables, because you declared them without using the `var` keyword.  That means all your calls to `countdown` will access the same variable.

Don't use the name of the variable in your `setTimeout`, or you'll get the current value of this global variable (the second one set).  Instead, use the *value* of the variable at the time you build the settimeout, like this:

```
setTimeout("t"+var_div+".countdown(" + var_anno + ", " + var_mese + ", " + var_giorno + ", " + var_ore + ", " + var_minuti + ", " + var_secondi + ",'" +  var_div + "')",1000);
```

In fact I don't see any need for this part at all:

```
var_div=nomediv;
var_anno=fineanno;
var_mese=finemese;
var_giorno=finegiorno;
var_ore=fineore;
var_minuti=fineminuti;
var_secondi=finesecondi;
```

Instead of using those new variables, you can just use the parameters that were passed in.  I suppose the reason you had that is so the `setTimeout` would have a variable to read the value from, but with my suggested change above it is no longer necessary.